# How to limit the scope in Google Cloud Platform Error Reporting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

We host quite a few things on our GCP project and it's kinda nice to be alerted on new errors, but I wish to send email notifications to Pagerduty only from my production kubernetes cluster.

Is there a way to do this, or should I filter this somehow in pagerduty (unsure if possible - still new with it).

Comment: I have updated my answer with some new findings,please have a look hope it helps!!!

Comment: Furthermore, there are 2 ways where we can send errors from Google Kubernetes Engine applications to Error Reporting 1.By logging to cloud logging 2.Using the Error Reporting API. Refer to this documentation for detailed steps, https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/kubernetes-engine#using_the_api

Answer (score 0):

Here is the procedure of sending notifications from kubernetes to pagerduty:

A metric needs to be created based on the requirement and that metric needs to be added when we create an alert. When we proceed further in the notifications page you can select pagerduty and proceed further in creating alerts.

**Step1:**

**Creating an log-based-Metric :**

1.In console go to **log-based metrics** page and there go to **create metric** and create a new custom metric.
[image]

2.Here set the metric type as counter and in details add log metric name as (user/delete).

3.In metric give the query which can fetch the logs of the errors you are expecting to be alerted and create the metric.

**Step 2:**

**Creating an alert policy :**

1.In the console go to the **Alerting page** and there go to **create policy** and create a new alerting policy.
[image]
2.Go to **add condition** and in that resource type is the resource which we need to be triggered (in our case kubernetes pod) and metric is the metric we created in step1.[image]
3.In filer add the project id and in period add the suitable period. Next in the configuration add these details and proceed to the next steps leaving the rest fields as default.[image]

**Step3:**

1.Next you will be directed to select notification channels there you go to Manage notification channels and select pager duty services and add  new and there add the display name and the service key and check connectivity save and proceed further.

2.Add the alert name and save the alert.
[image]